# How do I get ember-qunit to use my ApplicationAdapter instead of DS.FixtureAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to use `http-mock` as suggested by the `ember-cli` documentation instead of fixtures. I generated a mock and can verify (using curl) that my ember app serves it.

However, in testing, the adapter is set to `DS.FixtureAdapter` and I think this is the source of the problem. If I could do something like the following:

```
container.register('adapter:application', ApplicationAdapter)
```

I think it `moduleForModel()` would find my adapter, where I would import ApplicationAdapter from the adapter I want to use:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from 'myapp/adapters/application'
```

But I don't know where I can put this code. I tried hooking into the `delegate` callback, but it wasn't getting called by `moduleForModel()`.

Ideas about how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: Why is it set to `FixtureAdapter`?

Comment: @BuckDoyle, the `moduleForModel` method does a `container.lookupFactory('adapter:application')` and if that comes back false then it registers `DS.FixtureAdapter` to `adapter:application`. I was hoping I could get the container before this point and register my own `ApplicationAdapter`.

Comment: Why don’t you just set the adapter at `app/adapters/application`? I think the idea with `http-mock` is that you don’t use a different adapter for testing, you just mock out the server responses.

Comment: @BuckDoyle, what you describe is exactly what I would like to do and it works when doing integration tests. But I also wanted to do this with unit tests that don't boot the whole application. But for some reason in this setting, `moduleForModel` doesn't have an adapter registered and so it defaults to `FixtureAdapter`. I would like to register my adapter in the setup for unit tests, for example, but I don't know how to get the container and do that.

Comment: Hmm, and you can’t set the adapter afterward? Sadly this is outside my area of experience, hopefully someone else will come along who knows more.

Comment: @KevinBullaughey how did you get the `http-mock`s working for integration tests? My understanding is that the mocks run off of `localhost:4200/api`, which isn't necessarily running when the tests are... Do you have your integration tests running in CI?

Comment: @EliDupuis, I run two ember servers, one on port 4200 that I proxy to my rails back-end for by-hand usability testing in the browser, and another ember server on port 4201 that is unproxied, which I have configured testem to use by adding a `proxies` entry to `testem.json`. I modified my `http-mock` express `server/index.js` script along the lines of [this discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-disable-http-mock-server-within-environment-config-file/6660/9?u=kbullaughey) which means  the mocks are only used if I'm not proxying to rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, and thanks to the comments here I figured it out. :) Add the adapter to the `needs` property in the test:

```
moduleForModel('post', 'Post', {
  needs: ['adapter:application', ... ]
});
```

Comment: So simple! Worked like a charm.